# Mail domain pointed to another website when typed in a browser

Tags: apache, email, virtualhost

I have my Apache server configured for name-based virtual hosts and have multiple domains pointed to the same IP that is owned by my server.

Before I started a mail server on one of those domains. Each website behaves normally. But last month, I wanted to set up a mail server. I first created an A record (mail.site5.com). Then I created a MX record and pointed it to that A record. And then mail.site5.com is used for the mail server.

But I didn't add a virtualhost for it in the Apache config file. Due to this, I found out today that if I type mail.site5.com into a browser, my first website www.site1.com is opened.

Maybe this is why Google Webmaster couldn't connect to my new site www.site5.com.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: I doubt whether this was the reason why Google Webmaster couldn't connect to your new site. What error is it giving you?

Comment: hosting problems are not generally suited for SO - try superuser.com or serverfault.com

Comment: Google gives me an error saying "verification failed. we were unable to connect to your server." Just now I managed to use DNS verification to successfully verify my site. But I then got a DNS error saying my site is unreachable.